# search_up: undefined method 'untaint' error after Ruby upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

amateur coder here. In order to upgrade my Heroku stack, I have to move to a later Ruby version. I followed a tutorial to upgrade to Ruby 3.2.

After the upgrade, any time I try to do anything such as 'rails s' or 'bundle update', I get the error below. I've searched a lot online but can't find much of any use.

Any thoughts?

Many thanks for any tips

```
ec2-user:~/environment/website (master) $ bundle update

/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:272:in `search_up': undefined method `untaint' for "/home/ec2-user/environment/website":String (NoMethodError)

  current  = File.expand_path(SharedHelpers.pwd).untaint
                                                ^^^^^^^^
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:259:in `find_file'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:251:in `find_gemfile'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:27:in `root'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:234:in `root'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:246:in `app_config_path'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:273:in `settings'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/feature_flag.rb:21:in `block in settings_method'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:97:in `<class:CLI>'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:7:in `<module:Bundler>'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/lib/ruby/3.2.0+1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/lib/ruby/3.2.0+1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0-preview1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: does `bundle exec rails s` produce the same output?

Answer (score 34):

Please check before installed `Gemfile.lock`
you should remove Gemfile.lock before. ( cause, lock file is depends on old version ruby )

Comment: Is there no way to do this without removing the whole file?

Answer (score 15):

Ruby 3.2.0 has removed some deprecated methods (taint/trust/untaint/untrust) ,ref: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16131 . Bundler version 1.17.3 has that method in shared_helpers.rb . Try updating bundler to 2.4.1 .

Comment: FYI i needed to *uninstall* bundler 1.14 before installing bundler 3.2 --- something like `gem uninstall bundler --version '<2' && gem install bundler` should work